# fixed Positioning of a dialog/Div inside a mobile window irrespective of zooming

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, mobile

I am generating a dialog box via JS and positioning it center, for an non scrollable page, but when I open it on mobile page, the problem occurs is when I zoom the page the the Dialog div also zooms and move out of the window, thus making it inaccessible. 
What is the way to always make it fixed in the center or inside regardless of zooming, so that the content is accessible and readable.

Comment: I'm not sure you're going to be able to achieve this. You can try using position:fixed but as you can see from http://caniuse.com/#search=fixed it has limited support and I'm not sure how it behaves when zooming. Your best bet would probably be to disable user zooming but this might not be suitable for your application and has obvious accessibility issues. You could try checking scroll position and re-positoning your div based on that??

Comment: Having to zoom in order to "see" or "use" content on a mobile site is bad practice.

Comment: @sam_7_h this is a feature, since I dont wan't to make the zooming off, so want to integrate this as the feature.

Comment: on page zoom you should trigger a resize on your dialog window